# glGenBuffers returning non-unique names

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer

I thought that this was impossible but I'm seeing it with my software.  I have built a wrapper object to manage my buffer objects (I am working with shared contexts so I can't use VAOs), and the VBO side of things was working fine until I starting testing it with IBOs (glDrawElements(), I'm using a pure OpenGL 3+ environment).

Here is the code for adding a buffer to my object (Sy_GLObject):

```
QList< uint > Sy_GLObject::addBuffers( uint numBuffers, GLenum target,
                                       GLenum numericType, GLenum usage )
{
    uint* adds = new uint[numBuffers];
    glGenBuffers( numBuffers, adds );

    QList< uint > l;
    for ( uint i = 0; i < numBuffers; ++i ) {
            Buffer buffer( target, adds[i], 0, numericType, usage );
            buffers_ << buffer;

            l << i;
    }
    delete[] adds;

    Sy_GL::checkError();
    return l;
}
```

And the buffer names returned by this function are fine, until it is called by this code:

```
void Sy_BVH::initialiseGLObject()
{
    Sy_application::getMainWindow()->getActiveProject(
                                        )->getModelContext()->makeCurrent();

    GLuint vLoc = Sy_settings::get( "shader/flat/vertexLoc" ).toUInt();
    drawBBs_ = Sy_GLObject::createObject();

    //  Add vertex array.
    drawBBs_->addBuffers( 1 );
    drawBBs_->buffers()[0].setVertexPointer( vLoc );

    //  Add indices array.
    drawBBs_->addBuffers( 1, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT );
}
```

For some reason the indices array and vertex array names are both the same!  setVertexPointer() does not actually call glVertexAttribPointer(), it just stores the parameters for it in a POD class - *so no OpenGL calls are made between the two addBuffers() commands*.  The vertex call is 'correct' as it is one higher than the previous glGenBuffers() result, but from addBuffers() point of view there should be no difference between the calls.

Are there circumstances where glGenBuffers can possibly return the name of a buffer already in use!?

Thanks!

**Update**
To make sure threading was not a factor, I wrapped a static mutex around the glGenBuffers() block.

```
QMutexLocker locker( &mutex_ ); // mutex_ is a QMutex static class member.
uint* adds = new uint[numBuffers];
glGenBuffers( numBuffers, adds );
locker.unlock();
```

But it had absolutely no effect...

Comment: Are you by any chance in a threaded environment?

Comment: _Possibly_, this is all running inside a Qt-based GUI which does thread various parts.  It certainly makes sense, I'll do more tests.

Comment: As per the update, I mutexed the glGenBuffers() block but to no avail.  I'm wondering if glGenBuffers can be called implicitly by other OpenGL functions circumventing my thread protection?

Comment: It seems only glBindBuffers() can call glGenBuffers() implicitly, however in my code only my GL wrapper object calls this function directly and it only uses the addresses supplied by glGenBuffers().  This is driving me crazy now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Ilian Dinev over at the OpenGL.org forums for pointing out this stupid error.  I created my Buffer object on the stack and conveniently had it's destructor call glDeleteBuffers().  Fantastic bit of design.

Comment: Thank you, I've been struggling with something similar for a couple of weeks, this post made me put breakpoints on my glDeleteBuffers, and found I was doing exactly the same thing